Can't find variable: require at global code@
I'm new to JavaScript and was trying to import the Google Gemini library to use its AI. However, I'm facing an issue when I use the "require" keyword:
ERROR: Can't find variable: require at global code@

Here is the code that throws this error:
const {
    GoogleGenerativeAI,
    // HarmCategory,
    // HarmBlockThreshold,
  } = require("@google/generative-ai");


Try removing
const {
  GoogleGenerativeAI,
  HarmCategory,
  HarmBlockThreshold,
} = require("@google/generative-ai");

And replace with
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

